# How to remember state of a class not primary type in jetpack compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

Hi developers in jetpack compose if i do this:

```
var model by remember{ mutableStateOf(false)}
```

It works !!

but why if i do this:

```
 var model by remember{ mutableStateOf(Register())}
```

Register is a class:

```
class Register {
    var correo: String=""
    var password: String=""
    var nombre: String=""
    var apellido: String=""
    var direccion: String=""
    var telefono: String=""
    var confirmacion: String=""
}
```

but the second way is not binding properties
How can i do that?

Comment: What do you mean by not binding properties? when you `remember` an Object it will be contained in memory block that contains remember as long as your `Composable` that has this remember is in composition or you change `model` with new `Register` object.

Comment: I mean that if I update the variable false to true, it detects the changes in the viewmodel, but if I change any of the properties of the var model by remember{ mutableStateOf(Register())} to model.nombre="something" or any other, the changes are not detected and the new value is not saved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Compose to trigger recomposition you need to change value of

```
 var model by remember{ mutableStateOf(Register())}
```

because by default `mutableStateOf` uses `SnapshotMutationPolicy` that checks if **two instances are equal**

```
fun <T> mutableStateOf(
    value: T,
    policy: SnapshotMutationPolicy<T> = structuralEqualityPolicy()
): MutableState<T> = createSnapshotMutableState(value, policy)
fun <T> structuralEqualityPolicy(): SnapshotMutationPolicy<T> =
    StructuralEqualityPolicy as SnapshotMutationPolicy<T>

private object StructuralEqualityPolicy : SnapshotMutationPolicy<Any?> {
    override fun equivalent(a: Any?, b: Any?) = a == b

    override fun toString() = "StructuralEqualityPolicy"
}
```

You can either do this by creating a new SnapshotMutationPolicy or

setting new `Register` instance to your `model`. I think easiest way is to use a **data class** and create a new instance with data class copy function which creates a new instance allowing you to alter some of its properties while keeping the rest unchanged

```
data class Register (
    var correo: String=""
    var password: String=""
    var nombre: String=""
    var apellido: String=""
    var direccion: String=""
    var telefono: String=""
    var confirmacion: String=""
)

var model by remember { mutableStateOf(Register()) }

model = model.copy(password = "new password")
```